# How to convert time to number in excel?

Tags: excel, time, numbers

How do you convert time in [h]:mm format to number in excel

for example:

```
35:39 to  35
03:15 to 3
17:55 to 17
```

I tried dividing `61:32` (in [h]:mm format) by `01:00` and got `13`, but I want `61`.

Please also show how to round up or down,

for example

```
36:43  to 37
36:14 to 36
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: What is the format? Always hours:minutes? What are the constraints and range of values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this formula.

`=INT(A1*24)`

[image]

As barry mentioned you can use `=ROUND(A1*24,0)` for rounding up

[image]

Comment: because there is no rounding up/down in 35:39

Comment: and how to round up/down?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by roundup? why does the roundup doesn't happen in 35:39 but in 36:43?

Comment: If you want to round to the nearest hour try ROUND, `=ROUND(A1*24,0)`

Comment: @barryhoudini: Thanks barry and hence my question. either we can follow the `=INT(A1*24)` or `=ROUND(A1*24,0)` but we cannot have `35:39 = 35` and `36:43 = 37` at the same time

Comment: I think alwbtc is asking two different questions, Sid, so `=INT(A1*24)` answers the first, `=ROUND(A1*24)` answers the second. Btw you **can** divide by `01:00` too, i.e. syntax like this `=INT(A1\"1:00")` - that will get same result as multiplying by 24

Comment: @barryhoudini: `I think alwbtc is asking two different questions` I think you are right here :)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout could you please explain how `=INT(A1*24)` works? Why do we multiply `A1` with 24?

Answer (score 2):

If data are hh:mm, then `=MINUTE(A1/60+TIME(0,0,30))`. This gives the rounding as well.

Without rounding: `=MINUTE(A1/60)`.

**EDIT**: 
As commented by barry houdini, this only works for results less than 60, so its use is limited (and, in particular, for one of the cases exemplified by the OP). It could be adapted to meet the demands of the OP, with a more convoluted formula. There is no use in mending the formula, as the [answer by Siddarth Rout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528039/2707864) works ok.

I am leaving the answer here only for the case someone (perhaps even the OP) finds the idea used here useful.

Comment: But it is 2 hours and 54 minutes

Comment: you have misunderstood the question :) `=MINUTE(A1+TIME(0,0,30))` for `35:39` will return `39` and not `35` :)

Comment: I guess OP is slightly confused. I have asked for more clarifications. your formula will give `36` for `35:39` and OP wants `35`

Comment: I want to know how to get 35 and how to get 36 from 35:39

Comment: @alwbtc: I have shown you how to get 35. Sancho has shown you how to get 36

Comment: @alwbtc - I gave two similar formulas, with/without rounding.

Comment: This will only work when the time values are 59 hours or less (and alwbtc quotes 61:32 in edited question), using `MINUTE` gives that limitation

Comment: @barryhoudini - You are right. I have edited the answer... I was in doubt about deleting it, I guess it may still be useful.